# Evaluate expression with an arbitrary object shown in IDEA debugger as "this"

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

IDEA's ["Evaluate expression"](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/evaluating-expressions.html) feature is excellent. However, I sometimes find that I want to call a method of some object accessible under Variables or Result. Often I can write an expression which returns this object (e.g. like `myExpression.field1.field2.get(3)`) and then call the methods by `myExpression.field1.field2.get(3).method()`, then `myExpression.field1.field2.get(3).method2("asd")` etc.

But is there a way to mark an object as "this", so I could just evaluate `method()` and `method2("asd")`? Even better would be to give a short name to the object, so I could work with 2 or more at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turns out to be [Mark Object](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/09/referencing-marked-objects-in-expression-evaluation/):

> In IntelliJ IDEA 10 the feature has been extended and now you can reference marked object in debugger’s expressions by the label.
>
> In Evaluation dialog, Watches panel or breakpoint condition field a marked object can be referenced as if a local variable named {label-name}_DebugLabel was defined in the same context where the expression is evaluated. Such pseudo-variables are also suggested in completion popups.
>
> This extended functionality allows you to lookup a marked object even if it is not available from the current debugger’s context and adds extra expressiveness and flexibility to a user-defined breakpoint conditions and evaluated expressions.